# Viewport meta tag and mobile style sheet getting completely ignored by browser. Why is this happening?

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport, meta-tags

I'm trying to set up a website so that it uses a viewport meta tag to make the page initially zoomed out all of the way, and then use a separate stylesheet to render the page if it is on mobile. This should work, but will not render in anything I try it. What am I doing wrong? I've tried placing the link and meta tags at different places in the head, but nothing makes a difference. It validates fine through the w3c validator.

Here's the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Website</title>

    <link href="mobile.css" rel="sylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)">
    <link href="desktop.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    </head>
```

Comment: Which mobile browser?  Are you certain your device is 480px wide or less?

Comment: Yeah, I even tried 1px and still nothing. Firefox mobile, opera mobile, the default android browser.

Comment: try putting mobile.css after desktop.css.. Could just be an issue of priority on styles. It's hard to say if that would be the cause of your problem or not though.

Comment: What Blake said. As an extra precaution, you can add a `min-device-width` to the media query for the desktop CSS.

Comment: By the way, not that it helps, but I believe the current concensus is to use only one CSS file and put all the media queries in there instead of using multiple links.

Comment: Yeah, I know that makes more sense but this is how my textbook does it. I'm trying to work through the hands on exercises where it shows you what the code should be and walks you through everything, and I have exactly what the book has, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="desktop.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 400px)" />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).